# Strange Striped Insect identification (Northern Indiana)

Tags: zoology, species-identification, entomology

These bugs are coming out of some wood that I cut and burned in Northern Indiana (USA) . I am not sure if it is coming out of a white ash, cherry or oak.  We did have the emerald ash boarer come though the area -- is this an ash boarer?

Thanks.

[image: Indiana firewood Bug]

Comment: It's not an ash borer. You can learn more about Banded ash borers (*Neoclytus caprea*)  that are sometimes confused for this borer species [here](http://bygl.osu.edu/content/firewood-beetles-flare-0). See [here](http://www.emeraldashborer.info/) for information on the more commonly recognized emerald ash borer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is *actually* a **Painted hickory borer (*Megacyllene caryae*)**.

According to the [Virginia Cooperative Extension](https://pubs.ext.vt.edu/ENTO/ENTO-141/ENTO-141-pdf.pdf) (and [here](https://beetlesinthebush.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/when-is-a-locust-borer-not-a-locust-borer/)), this species is *frequently* misidentified as a **Locust Borer beetle (*Megacyllene robiniae*)**.

Here are their pictures side-by-side ([*M. robiniae*](http://www.billhubick.com/images/201409/locust_borer_fsp_md_20140927_02.jpg) on the left and [*M. caryae*](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQIiokf0Iu3J901vOtlyqUa3LXU9lFz0DxMIQOdbxMPp-2MM3h1og) on the right):

[image: Borer Beetles]

Pretty similar, right? There are some differences though:

- Appearance:

  - *M. robiniae* description (from [Virginia Cooperative Extension](https://pubs.ext.vt.edu/ENTO/ENTO-141/ENTO-141-pdf.pdf)):

    > Both males and females have black bodies with **bright yellow markings**. These markings are most notable in the "W" on the first pair of wings.  Legs are red and antennae are black. These long antennae place it among the "long-horned" beetles.
  - The distinction for ***M. caryae*** is the white 'W' stripe. From OSU Extension:

    > The first marking from front-to-back on the elytra is also a yellow horizontal band; however, **the second marking appears as a distinct "W" that is light yellow to cream-colored**.

The following image from the [Ohio State Extension](http://bygl.osu.edu/content/firewood-beetles-flare-0) better demonstrates the **white** W markings of *M. caryae* (similar to the OP's picture):

[image: M. caryae]

- These two insects also differ in **Behavior** ( this is important).

  - From OSU Extension:

    > Painted hickory borers emerge from cut wood in the **spring** and locust borers emerge from live trees in **late summer to early fall**.
  - Since the OP found this in the spring *coming from firewood*, it further points to the painted hickory borer.
- Finally, they differ in the species they infest:

  - From the Virginia Cooperative Extension:

    > The locust borer is a native insect that attacks black locust (Robinia pseudoacacia L.) and its ornamental cultivars... Unlike locust borer adults, painted hickory borer adults...attack stressed or recently cut hickory and other hardwoods.
  - ***M. caryae*** is named for it's preferred wood, the hickories (*Carya* spp.).

    - According to OSU Extension, *M. caryae* also commonly infests the recently dead wood of ash, black locust, hackberry, honeylocust, oak, Osage orange, walnut, and butternut trees.
  - *M. robiniae*, on the other hand, gets it name from the larvae living in and eating their typical host tree, black locust (*Robinia pseudoacacia*). Adults are also often found eating goldenrod species.

**Should you be concerned**? Not according to the OSU Extension page:

> Fortunately, painted hickory borers only infest dead wood that has been cut for less than one year. ... The beetles will not infest older dead wood; they will not infest wood that has been dried or processed into home furnishings, or used as structural wood.  So, beetles that emerge from infested firewood in or around a home are only a nuisance pest.

A quick search for *M. caryae* turns up few other sources, but you can find additional fact sheets for *M. robiniae* [here](https://extension.usu.edu/files/publications/factsheet/locust-borers02.pdf), [here](http://www.colostate.edu/Dept/CoopExt/4dmg/Pests/locborer.htm), and [here](https://www.ces.ncsu.edu/depts/ent/notes/O&T/trees/note18/note18.html).

---

For those that don't know trees: here is a [link](http://forestry.about.com/cs/treeid/a/the_hickory.htm) to learn more about the common North America hickory species, and below are some [images](http://texastreeid.tamu.edu/content/listOfTrees/index.aspx?t=H) of common hickory species. More info about black locust (*Robinia pseudoacacia*) can be found [here](http://texastreeid.tamu.edu/content/TreeDetails/?id=112).

[image: Carya Species]

Comment: I updated this answer with the correct ID and the often misidentified look-alike (which I originally fell for). As a result, you get a two-for-one beetle lesson for the day :p

Comment: Thank you for the well described and documented answer, as well as answering my follow up question: "Should I be concerned".

Comment: For fun: [Mating Frenzy of painted hickory borers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2jnDnser64) on youtube!